# Whether Calendar Helper Plugin works fine for rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins

Whether Calendar Helper Plugin works fine for rails3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but fount the following with Rails on its github issues:

When rendering sass it doesn't seem to render links from a "render_calendar_cell" method properly any longer in rails 3, probably due to the new implicit "raw".

If skipping raw it renders the links but outputs escaped text.

```
= raw calendar(:year => @year, :month => @month, :first_day_of_week => 1) do |d|
  - render_calendar_cell(d)  / returns <a href> link
```

https://github.com/topfunky/calendar_helper/issues#issue/4